# How to insert list in a ODE:

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, ode

I am trying to numerically solve the following ODE

[image: y''(x)=-0.5*f(x)*y'(x)]

with boundary conditions

```
y(x=0)=0;y(x=20)=1
```

Where f(x) is the solution of another ODE that I already solved numerically. I am trying to solve my ODE with https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_bvp.html, but the problem that I have is that f(x) is written as a list for

```
 coordinates x = np.arange(0,20.01,0.05)
```

and I do not know how to insert the list in scipy.integrate.solve_bvp to obtain the solution of ODE.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to solve the coupled system, that is to integrate the DE for `f` at the same time as the current DE. If this is a variant of your previous problem on math.SE then this coupled approach is unavoidable.

As for the literal solution, use interpolation

```
def f(x): return numpy.interp(x, x_samples, f_samples)
```

and then call this function in the ODE function

```
def y_ODE(x,y): return [y[1], -0.5*f(x)*y[1]]
```